# Is there any way I can get friends' contact number using Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, api, get, friend

We're developing an application which needs to get the contact number of fb friend. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean phone number, I don't think it's possible at this time. Here is what you can request for: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/